# Date in Userform Text.Box not showing the data inserted

Tags: vba, date, outlook, textbox, userform

i have a simple userform with a textbox where the user inserts a date and another textbox where the user inserts a number. When i try to use the data from the form it will not show the inserted data: the date shows as 12:00:00 am and the numeber shows as 0 .

Here is the userform

```
Public Sub CancelButton_Click()
 Unload Me
 End
End Sub

Public Sub UserForm_Initialize()
 TextBox1.Value = ""
 TextBox2.Value = ""
End Sub

Public Sub btnOK_Click()
Dim xSO As Date
Dim ySO As String
 xSO = Format(TimeValue(TextBox1.Value), "dd.mm.yyyy")
 ySO = TextBox2.Value
Unload Me
End Sub
```

Here is the minimum sub:

```
Public xSO As Long, ySO As Long
    Sub ffffff()
    Dim x As Date, y As String
            UserForm19.Show

             x = xSO 'Format(TextBox1.Value, "dd.mm.yyyy")
             y = ySO 'UserForm19.TextBox2.text

    MsgBox x
    MsgBox y

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared xSO and ySO twice.

Remove the local declaration from Public Sub btnOK_Click()

```
Dim xSO As Date
Dim ySO As String
```